# M3U8 Playlist with autoplay enable (HLS)

Tags: html, http-live-streaming, playlist, m3u8

I need some source code for a M3U8 playplist, support to mp3 and acc too. Someone have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you need exactly , do you need an HLS free web player which support playlist?
if yes then you can try this one & for more options you can sign up :
http://playerjs.com/docs/en=code